# Pattern Flood Fill Algorithm

Tags: c, algorithm, graphics

I have implemented a flood fill algorithm that is working correctly for solid color fills. Now I´m working on a pattern fill and decided to add a flag to see how to fill the area ( with a color or with a pattern). However when using the  the algorithm with pattern fill gets stuck while painting the area.

This is my original code that works with solid colors:

```
void floodFillStack(int x, int y, byte newColor, byte oldColor) {
    int y1;
    if (oldColor == newColor) return;
    if (get_pixel(x, y) != oldColor) return;
    //draw current scanline from start position to the top 
    y1 = y;
    while (y1 < h && get_pixel(x, y1) == oldColor) {
        plot_pixel(x, y1, newColor);
        y1++;
    }    

    //draw current scanline from start position to the bottom
    y1 = y - 1;
    while (y1 >= 0 && get_pixel(x, y1) == oldColor) {
        plot_pixel(x, y1, newColor);
        y1--;
    }

    //test for new scanlines to the left
    y1 = y;
    while (y1 < h && get_pixel(x, y1) == newColor) {
        if (x > 0 && get_pixel(x - 1, y1) == oldColor) {
            floodFillStack(x - 1, y1, newColor, oldColor);
        } 
        y1++;
    }
    y1 = y - 1;
    while (y1 >= 0 && get_pixel(x, y1) == newColor) {
        if (x > 0 && get_pixel(x - 1, y1) == oldColor) {
            floodFillStack(x - 1, y1, newColor, oldColor);
        }
        y1--;
    } 

    //test for new scanlines to the right 
    y1 = y;
    while (y1 < h && get_pixel(x, y1) == newColor) {
        if (x < w - 1 && get_pixel(x + 1, y1) == oldColor) {           
            floodFillStack(x + 1, y1, newColor, oldColor);
        } 
        y1++;
    }
    y1 = y - 1;
    while (y1 >= 0 &&get_pixel(x, y1) == newColor) {
        if (x < w - 1 && get_pixel(x + 1, y1) == oldColor) {
            floodFillStack(x + 1, y1, newColor, oldColor);
        }
        y1--;
    }
}
```

And here is with the pattern modification (it still works with solid colors).

```
int pattern1[6][6] = { {0,1,0,1,0,1},
                       {1,0,1,0,1,0},
                       {0,1,0,1,0,1},
                       {1,0,1,0,1,0},
                       {0,1,0,1,0,1},
                       {1,0,1,0,1,0} };             
int pattern2[6][6] = { {0,0,1,1,0,0},
                       {0,1,0,0,1,0},
                       {1,0,0,0,0,1},
                       {1,0,0,0,0,1},
                       {0,1,0,0,1,0},
                       {0,0,1,1,0,0} };

void floodFillStack(int x, int y, byte newColor, byte oldColor, int pattern_fill) {
    int y1;
    if (oldColor == newColor) return;
    if (get_pixel(x, y) != oldColor) return;
    //draw current scanline from start position to the top 
    y1 = y;
    while (y1 < h && get_pixel(x, y1) == oldColor) {
        if (pattern_fill == 0) {
            if (fill_pattern == 1) {
                if (pattern1[x%6][y1%6] == 1) {
                    plot_pixel(x, y1, newColor);
                }
            } else {
                if (pattern2[x%6][y1%6] == 1) {
                    plot_pixel(x, y1, newColor);    
                }               
            }
        } else {                
            plot_pixel(x, y1, newColor);
        }
        y1++;
    }    
    //draw current scanline from start position to the bottom
    y1 = y - 1;
    while (y1 >= 0 && get_pixel(x, y1) == oldColor) {
        if (pattern_fill == 0) {
            if (fill_pattern == 1) {
                if (pattern1[x%6][y1%6] == 1) {
                    plot_pixel(x, y1, newColor);
                }
            } else {
                if (pattern2[x%6][y1%6] == 1) {
                    plot_pixel(x, y1, newColor);
                }               
            }
        } else {
            plot_pixel(x, y1, newColor);
        }
        y1--;
    }
    //test for new scanlines to the left
    y1 = y;
    while (y1 < h && get_pixel(x, y1) == newColor) {
        if (x > 0 && get_pixel(x - 1, y1) == oldColor) {
            floodFillStack(x - 1, y1, newColor, oldColor, pattern_fill);
        } 
        y1++;
    }
    y1 = y - 1;
    while (y1 >= 0 && get_pixel(x, y1) == newColor) {
        if (x > 0 && get_pixel(x - 1, y1) == oldColor) {
            floodFillStack(x - 1, y1, newColor, oldColor, pattern_fill);
        }
        y1--;
    } 
    //test for new scanlines to the right 
    y1 = y;
    while (y1 < h && get_pixel(x, y1) == newColor) {
        if (x < w - 1 &&get_pixel(x + 1, y1) == oldColor) {           
            floodFillStack(x + 1, y1, newColor, oldColor, pattern_fill);
        } 
        y1++;
    }
    y1 = y - 1;
    while (y1 >= 0 && get_pixel(x, y1) == newColor) {
        if (x < w - 1 && get_pixel(x + 1, y1) == oldColor) {
            floodFillStack(x + 1, y1, newColor, oldColor, pattern_fill);
        }
        y1--;
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me see the problem?

**EDIT:**

Thanks to WeatherVane for the suggestion. The algorithm is no longer stuck, but it does not cover the entire area. Here´s a picture:

[image]

Comment: Remove the empty lines and indent the code properly.

Comment: @PabloEstrada If your flood space is not too big, you may consider using recursion. The code will be a lot simpler.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I´m concerned about memory. I did try using recursion but I ran out of stack when using that algorithm, that´s why I changed it to the one in the question.

Comment: I can see `pattern_fill` but not `fill_pattern`. And you are not filling when there is a `0` element in `pattern1` or `pattern2`. Should you be using those masks to fill with one of two colours, rather than do nothing?

Comment: Hello Thanks. The fill_pattern is a global variable in my program just to choose between pattern1 and pattern2. I always have it set to 1 right now. I represent the 0 as an "empty" pixel so I´m just concerned with painting if I have a 1 on my matrix. Do you think this is a problem for the algorithm?

Comment: Why don't you try my suggestion and use a `0` in the mask to paint one colour (different fom the background) and `1` to paint another colour (ditto)? You'll have to stop testing for `newColor` and only test for `oldColour`, by using `if (... != oldColor)`

Comment: Thank you! I´ve tried it and now it´s almost working I added a picture to the post. The algorithm is no longer stuck, but it won´t cover all the area-

Comment: Did you notice my (edited in) suggestion to also change `(... == newColor)` to  `(... != oldColor)` ?

Comment: I forgot a while loop... Thanks it now works perfectly! Could you please post it as an answer so I can mark it as accepted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your floodfill is likely to misfire if you ignore the `0` values in your pattern masks. Instead of that, always fill with one of two colours (both different from the background).

You will also have to change some of your conditional tests. Instead of

```
(... == newColor)
```

you could use

```
(... != oldColor)
```

or

```
(... == newColor1 || ... == newColor2)
```

Answer (score 1):

When you fill with a solid color, every pixel that starts at `oldColor` gets changed to `newColor`. This means that a test of that pixel later in the process won't match against it again.

When you try to fill with a pattern, some of those pixels are going to remain as `oldColor`. You get stuck in an infinite loop, retesting those same pixels over and over.